# JQuery.get Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been going crazy trying to figure this out.  I have a PHP script that returns true/false with the header set to Content-Type: text/plain.

When I use a simple .get like this:

```
$.get("ip.php");
```

I can see the call and the data loaded in firebug.

However when I try to add more complexity I get "SyntaxError: syntaxerror".  This is the jquery I am using:

```
var hello;
$.get('ip.php', function(data){
   hello = data;
   console.log(hello);
});

if (hello == "false") {
    $( "#status").removeclass("working").addClass("notworking");
    $(".stat").html("<li class="title">STATUS: NOT WORKING</li>");
} else {
    $(".stat").html("<li class="title">STATUS: WORKING</li>");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: Return $.get() callback to outer scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266872/jquery-return-get-callback-to-outer-scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because AJAX calls are asynchronous — the conditional statement is evaluated before jQuery actually received a response from the server and updated the `hello` variable.

Therefore, the solution is to move the conditional statement into the success callback of `$.get()`.

p/s: Also, you are not escaping the string in `.html()` properly. Either use `\"` to escape double quotes, or use single quotes, i.e. `'`.

```
var hello;
$.get('ip.php', function(data){
    hello = data;
    if (hello == "false") {
        $( "#status").removeclass("working").addClass("notworking");
        $(".stat").html("<li class=\"title\">STATUS: NOT WORKING</li>");
    } else {
        $(".stat").html("<li class=\"title\">STATUS: WORKING</li>");
    }
});
```

**Even better:** use [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) instead, like `.done()`, `.fail()`, `.always()` and etc (whenever you see fit). They offer better versatility and allows you to check for the status of the AJAX call anywhere in your code:

```
var ip = $.get('ip.php'); /* Make GET request */

/* Deferred object */
ip.done(function(data){
    if (data == "false") {
        $( "#status").removeclass("working").addClass("notworking");
        $(".stat").html("<li class=\"title\">STATUS: NOT WORKING</li>");
    } else {
        $(".stat").html("<li class=\"title\">STATUS: WORKING</li>");
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // Optional
    // console.log('.get failed ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
}).always(function(){
    // Optional
    // console.log('$.get completed regardless of status');
});
```

Comment: Also need to fix the quotes around title: `"<li class="title">STATUS: NOT WORKING</li>"`.

Comment: @SlipperyPete Thanks! Will fix that ;)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am still getting a syntax error thrown at me however.  When I check firebug it says "SyntaxError: syntax error" followed by `<script type="text/javascript">
var hello;
$.get('ip.php', function (data)  else });
      </script>` with an arrow pointing at else.

Comment: `var hello; $.get('templates/blnket/ip.php', function (data) else });` This is not valid JS. The code I have in the answer has been validated.

Comment: Yeah, thats the weird part.  I used the code you gave me and when I check the console it shows the invalid JS that I pasted in the last comment.  In an effort to check that I am not completely crazy I tried this code from the jquery docs `$.get( "ip.php", function( data ) {
          alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });` and that also comes back with the syntaxerror message.

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: Yes, I do.  I am using version 2.1.1 from Googles CDN.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer is correct, it is **not** the source of the error you are seeing.  The error is coming from these lines:

```
    $(".stat").html("<li class="title">STATUS: NOT WORKING</li>");
} else {
    $(".stat").html("<li class="title">STATUS: WORKING</li>");
```

Note the syntax highlighting.  You're trying to use quote marks inside a string, which actually ends the string.  You can either escape them like this:

```
    $(".stat").html("<li class=\"title\">STATUS: NOT WORKING</li>");
} else {
    $(".stat").html("<li class=\"title\">STATUS: WORKING</li>");
```

Or use single-quotes instead of double-quotes somewhere:

```
    $(".stat").html('<li class="title">STATUS: NOT WORKING</li>');
} else {
    $(".stat").html('<li class="title">STATUS: WORKING</li>');
```